Adding user defined unordered list styles[shapes] in the tinymce list plugin - vue js
I am using tinymce 7 version in vue.js 3 and using lists plugin and added the **bullist **for unordered list purpose, where I have a requirement I need to add a shape [like star,hexagon] which is not available in tinymce plugin, by default circle,square only available, if I add any icons, its name is getting appended to the style like [e.g : icon name : list-bull-star, the star is getting set in the style but since css doesnot has it, it is showing numbers as default when clicked]. How to restrict this and add our desired shaped in unordered list and make it work when clicked ?
I tried adding the icons and I added svgs to the icons pack and now I tried and made it to get displayed under the unordered list drop down , when clicked the style is getting set with the icon name we gave
I want to restrict the setting of the style name and need to set the symbol what we give in the unordered list
